# NPM isn't building while I've npm 5.0.0 during creation of laravel authentication page

Tags: laravel

This is actually the problem with my npm. building process.
Don't know why it is being such kind of issue while I have npm 5.0.0 and 8.0.0.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: If you could provide some more information to help understand your problem, others may be able to provide a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely to be an issue with the permissions, try to run it as sudo (admin).